# Chef kitchen converge instance requires ssh password

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

To run `kitchen converge` and set up my test kitchen vagrant instance, such as in this [guide](https://learn.chef.io/local-development/rhel/get-started-with-test-kitchen/https://learn.chef.io/local-development/rhel/get-started-with-test-kitchen/), I have noticed that I must first create a `$COOKBOOK_ROOT_DIR/.kitchen/default-centos-72.yml` file.  After the file has been created with `kitchen converge` I must then `control + c` edit the file to include the `password: vagrant` line and then run `kitchen converge` again.  In the end the file will look something like this:

```
---
hostname: 127.0.0.1
port: '2222'
username: vagrant
password: vagrant
ssh_key: "$COOKBOOK_ROOT_DIR/.kitchen/kitchen-vagrant/kitchen-$COOKBOOK_NAME-default-centos-72/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
last_action: converge
```

How can I have chef kitchen automatically know to use `password: vagrant` before running `kitchen converge`? Or better yet how can I have chef create test instances without any ssh passwords?

Comment: Are you using vagrant 1.8.5? It is known to have issues with Kitchen and we recommend 1.8.4.

Comment: yes I am using 1.8.5 ill try to use 1.8.4 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep @coderanger got it. I needed to downgrade to vagrant 1.8.4 and virtualbox 4.3.4 because virtualbox version 5+ doesnt work with vagrant 1.8.4.